# Is there a logic sentence that necessarily needs the valuation of all its components?

Tags: logic

Suppose we have an alphabet with $N$ propositional symbols $p_1,p_2,...,p_N$.
Is there a sentence that we cannot determine its valuation unless we determine all the valuations for $p_i$?

For example, I was thinking of something like $p_1 \to \big( p_2 \to (p_3 \to ...\big)$. This doesn't work quite well because if $p_1$ is False the expression can only be True, independently of the other $p_i$'s.

I was in the proccess of proving something in Propositional Logic, and my argument would become succint with this counter-example, so any ideia would help.

Comment: If we have a true conjunction, we'll need to prove all of it's conjuncts true in order to complete a proof (in intuitionistic logic... or if we can't use other connectives).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would xor be an example? Let $f(x_1, \dots, x_N) = x_1\oplus (x_2\oplus (\dots \oplus(x_{N-1}\oplus x_N)\dots))$, then $f(\dots, x_k, \dots) \ne f(\dots, \neg x_k, \dots)$ for all $k$.

Comment: xor is associative. Why not write $x_1 \oplus x_2 \oplus \cdots \oplus x_N$?

Comment: Surely it is. Maybe somehow I imitated the parenthesis for the given sentence in OP.

Comment: @lemontree I think $(0 \oplus 1) \oplus 1 = 1 \oplus 1 = 0$, and $(0\oplus 0) \oplus 1 = 0 \oplus 1 = 1$. Am i wrong?

Comment: No, I realized I made a mistake, sorry about that! (Can't undo my downvote though unless you edit your post.)

Comment: nvermind, thank you!

Comment: I was thinking along the fact that the semantics of exactly one of the disjuncts being true is not preserved when nesting binary XOR (e.g. $p \oplus (q \oplus r)$ also gets true when all three are true), but after some trying out it seems that nevertheless there is no combination where the truth value remains the same in varying the value of just one variable, and so the truth value of nested XOR is only fully determined with the values of all variables.

Comment: $p\oplus q $ acts like $p+q \pmod2$ so every $p_i$'s become switches which can change the parity of $\sum p_i$, i.e. which can change the resulting value